# Can't get my JSON Array in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

i need help to get my array array json in php.

here is my js code-

```
var data = {
    cp: $('#CPDem').val(),
    ville: $('#VilleDem').val(),
};

data = JSON.stringify(data);

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,//Je t'ai min asynchrone à false après à voir
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json', // dire que le type est en json
        url: 'test11.php',
        success: function(details) { },
        error: function(s) { }
        }, 
        "json");// a ne pas zappé le json a la fin de ajax()
```

and here is my php code

```
if (isset($_POST)){

    $tab = json_encode($_POST);

    var_dump($tab);

}
```

and this is my vardump response

```
/test11.php:9:string '{"{\"cp\":\"4564\",\"ville\":\"4664645546\",\"edition\":6}":""}'
```

the problems is that i need to get in array and not in string

someone can help me please ?

thanks in advance

Comment: try `echo $tab` instead of `var_dump($tab);`

Comment: You must decode the string, not encode the string :)

Comment: do json_decode($tab,true) instead of encode

Comment: eh, wait.. dont you already have an array in POST? as in, $tab=$_POST and be done with it?

Comment: Why not setting a real post field like `data: {posted:data},` then `json_decode($_POST['posted'],true)`

Comment: Just as Note: `dataType` is only for the response that ajax get.

Comment: Remove trailing comma on `ville: $('#VilleDem').val(),` this will get rid of the erronious data at end of post

Comment: You dont need `data = JSON.stringify(data);`

Comment: Data will arrive at the PHP as `$_POST['cp']` and `$_POST['ville']` So you dont need to `json_anything()` that data

Comment: This question does not make a lot of sense; if you send a json string, you'd need to read the raw input instead of using post. And where does `edition` come from all of a sudden on the server-side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Correct way to do:-***

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    data: {"cp": $('#CPDem').val(),"ville": $('#VilleDem').val()}, //proper way
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'test11.php',
    success:function(details){

    },
    error: function(s){

    }

}, "json");
```

***And php:-***

```
if (!empty($_POST)){
    var_dump($_POST);
    // It should look like this
    echo $_POST['cp'];
    echo $_POST['ville'];
}
```

Comment: See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488875/cant-get-my-json-array-in-array-php#comment72117490_42488875)

Comment: You dont need to `json_anything()` the recieved data. It will be placed in `$_POST['cp']` and `$_POST['ville']` by PHP automatically

Comment: i put JSON.stringify(data); because i have few field with quotes in another document and i don't like the replace function so i need to take in one time all of theses (fields)

Comment: @weymeels There is no need to send json just because of the quotes; if you send an object, jQuery will encode the data correctly so you can send whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is global variable which is already an array do not use `json_decode($_POST, true)` remove this statement.